# Python Tkinter Application won't load. No Error. (python)

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I made a (sad) game in where you click a chicken, and you get eggs. I had tested it and it was fully functioning, but I then add a main_loop(), and the console window opens, and it just has a flashing bold underscore, as it does when it is loading, but it does not load. Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import time

root = Tk()
root.title("Chicken Clicker")
eggz = 0
eggvalue = 0.2
eggzps = 0
chookz = 0

def main_loop():

    while 1:
        eggz = eggz + eggzps
        time.sleep(1)
def moar_eggz():
    global eggz, eggvalue, eggzps, chookz
    chookz = chookz + 1
    eggzps = round(chookz) / 0.1
    print round(chookz)
    if eggzps >= 10:
        print round(eggzps)
    elif eggzps < 10:
        print eggzps
while 1:
    eggzLabel = "Eggs: " + str(eggz)
    eggzpsLabel = "Eggs per second: " + str(eggzps)
    eggvalueLabel = "Egg Value: " + str(eggvalue)
    chookzLabel = " Chickens: " + str(chookz)
label4 = Label(root, text=eggzLabel)
label3 = Label(root, text=eggzLabel)
label2 = Label(root, text=eggzLabel)
label1 = Label(root, text=eggzLabel)
label4.pack()
label3.pack()
label2.pack()
label1.pack()
imagecnv = Image.open("img/1.png")
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(imagecnv)
main_loop()

openbutton = Button(root, image=photo, width = 500, height=500, command = moar_eggz)
openbutton.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `main_loop()` does not do anything besides sleeping and increment a variable. Forever.

Comment: You have two infinite loops in there other than root.mainloop().

Comment: `while 1` stops everything.

Comment: you can't use long-running elements like `while 1` or `sleep` because it stops `root.mainloop()` which do all job in GUI - it gets key/mouse events from system, sends events to widgets, redraws widgets, etc. `root.mainloop()` is like engine in car, if it can't run then car can't move.

Comment: use `root.after(milliseconds, function_name)` instead of `while` loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]Does this do the job?:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import time, threading

root = Tk()
root.title("Chicken Clicker")
eggz = 0
eggvalue = 0.2
eggzps = 0
chookz = 0

def main_loop():
    global eggz
    try:
        while True:
            eggz += eggzps
            time.sleep(1)
    except: pass
def moar_eggz():
    global eggz, eggvalue, eggzps, chookz
    chookz = chookz + 1
    eggzps = round(chookz) / 0.1
    print (round(chookz))
    if eggzps >= 10:
        print (round(eggzps))
    elif eggzps < 10:
        print (eggzps)
def update_labels():
    try:
        while True:
            eggzLabel = "Eggs: " + str(eggz)
            eggzpsLabel = "Eggs per second: " + str(eggzps)
            eggvalueLabel = "Egg Value: " + str(eggvalue)
            chookzLabel = " Chickens: " + str(chookz)
            label1.config (text=eggzLabel)
            label2.config (text=eggzLabel)
            label3.config (text=eggzLabel)
            label4.config (text=eggzLabel)
            time.sleep(0.2)
    except: pass
eggzLabel = "Eggs: " + str(eggz)
eggzpsLabel = "Eggs per second: " + str(eggzps)
eggvalueLabel = "Egg Value: " + str(eggvalue)
chookzLabel = " Chickens: " + str(chookz)
label4 = Label(root, text=eggzLabel)
label3 = Label(root, text=eggzLabel)
label2 = Label(root, text=eggzLabel)
label1 = Label(root, text=eggzLabel)
label4.pack()
label3.pack()
label2.pack()
label1.pack()
imagecnv = Image.open( "img\\1.png")
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(imagecnv)
threading.Thread (target = main_loop).start ()
threading.Thread (target = update_labels).start ()

openbutton = Button(root, image=photo, width = 500, height=500, command = moar_eggz)
openbutton.pack()

root.mainloop()
```